# Joblib nested Parallel execution not making use of available cores

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing, nested, joblib

By using nested Parallel statements with n_jobs>1 on the outer statement, the nested Parallel function appears to be restricted ressources available from 1 thread instead of 4.
I.e. consider the following strongly simplified script to reproduce the problem:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import numpy as np

def parallel_in_parallel_test(i):
    a = np.ones((1000,1000))
    for j in range(2000):
        a *= np.random.randn(1000,1000)
    return a.sum()

def parallel_in_parallel_wrapper(j, n_threads=4):
    out2 = Parallel(n_jobs=n_threads)(delayed(parallel_in_parallel_test)(i) for i in range(100))
    return np.array(out2).sum()

out = Parallel(n_jobs=3)(delayed(parallel_in_parallel_wrapper)(j, n_threads=4) for j in range(100))
```

I would have expected that 3 parallel processes produce 4 processes that yield a CPU usage of 400% ie 4 cores/threads per "parent-process". However, instead these 4 "child-processes" run not in parallel. Each "parent-process" uses 100% of the CPU instead of 400% (only a single core/thread)

Consider the following screenshot from htop:
[image: htop screenshot showing low number of active threads and high number of inactive threads]

I can reproduce the issue with a minimalistic environment:

```
conda create --name py39 python=3.9
conda activate py39
conda install numpy joblib
```

My OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

A not-nested approach is not feasible with my specific code as the nested parallel sits in a method of a class.

Any suggestions how to properly make use of the available ressources? Is it just a simple mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently changing the inner_max_num_threads limit of the backend used in the nested statement works - still it is not clear to me why this is neccessary in the first place.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed, parallel_backend
import numpy as np

def parallel_in_parallel_test(i):
    a = np.ones((1000,1000))
    for j in range(2000):
        a *= np.random.randn(1000,1000)
    return a.sum()

def parallel_in_parallel_wrapper(j, n_threads=4):
    with parallel_backend("loky", inner_max_num_threads=n_threads):
        out2 = Parallel(n_jobs=n_threads)(delayed(parallel_in_parallel_test)(i) for i in range(100))
    return np.array(out2).sum()

out = Parallel(n_jobs=3)(delayed(parallel_in_parallel_wrapper)(j, n_threads=4) for j in range(100))
```